# VNC server -> websockify -> noVNC issue

Tags: websocket, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

Hello i have a bit of a problem using websockify.

I made executable for windows, then i start my websockify in cmd:

c:\web\websockify.exe 192.168.1.70:5901 192.168.1.70:5900

WARNING: no 'resource' module, daemonizing is slower or disabled

WebSocket server settings:

- Listen on 192.168.1.70:5901
- Flash security policy server
- No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
- proxying from 192.168.1.70:5901 to 192.168.1.70:5900

so far all good. In the background VNC server is running on the same 
computer at port 5900. The thing is i need to use websockify to be
able to use novnc on the other computer in local network.

I have latest novnc installed on latest XAMPP server (apache 2.2).
When i start vnc.html it asks for server, port, password. I typed
them in and press connect. I get an error on the websockify side:

WARNING: no 'resource' module, daemonizing is slower or disabled

Usage:

```
websockify.exe [options] [source_addr:]source_port target_addr:target_port

websockify.exe [options] [source_addr:]source_port -- WRAP_COMMAND_LINE
```

websockify.exe: error: no such option: --multiprocessing-fork

I can't connect using noVNC. I searched for internet to find solution
but did not find it.

Can someone help me get this apps together runnig?

or is there some more windows friendly solution with some other app that
does what websockify does?

br

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you follow this guide? https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/wiki/Compiling-Websockify-as-Windows-Executable

Websockify uses the python multiprocessing module. This module is problematic on Windows, especially with older versions of python. You might try python 3.2 or greater and see if you have more success although no guarantees. Websockify is developed and tested on Linux only.

There used to be a pre-built version of Websockify for Windows that at least worked without multiprocessing (one client at a time), however, github dropped support for downloads so this build is no longer available.

**Disclaimer**: I made websockify.

Comment: yes i did follow the guide exactly. downloaded python 2.7, numpy for python 2.7 and py2exe for 2.7. Then i downloaded the last novnc source and in utils i made setup.py and then i build the exe file. so i can build it with 3.3 python ? what about numpy it's only for 2.7 python? can i build without numpy? I know u made it :), was hoping to get reply from u.

Comment: numpy is available for python 3.1 and up: http://scipy.github.com/faq.html#do-numpy-and-scipy-support-python-3-x The problem is py2exe doesn't seem to have python 3 support yet. You might try http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/. But you don't actually need to make an exe as long as you can run it the standard way. Also, if you come up with a process that works for python 3 with websockify, please add it to the websockify wiki :-)

Comment: ok i will try and write you if i succeed. thanks for answers.

Comment: well i tried, but still not work. i downloaded python 3.3, numpy and cx_freeze for 3.3 but the same problem after exe made. here is my setup.py example maybe something wrong there but i think not. `code` from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy.lib.format"]}

setup(name = "websockify",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "websockify",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("websockify")]
) `code` then i run it with python setup.py build and get exe which has same problem. maybe i have to find some other app.

Comment: i just noticed u have websockify written in c also. is it possible that i build that and try it on windows ? or is this not the whole thing?

Comment: @huntester, it's not a very well implemented version. You might have more luck with node.js version. See the comment at the top for how to use it: https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/other/websockify.js

Comment: one question: can with this also go over internet not just LAN? i mean is it possible with this to create server and then go over internet not LAN, and what do i need to do for that or is this automatic?

Comment: @huntester yes. As long as noVNC can communicate with websockify and websockify can communicate with your VNC server then it will work (i.e. as long as firewalls aren't blocking either connection). It will be less responsive unless you have a really low-latency connection, but it will work.